# Using MyBatis with Oracle XMLType function "existsNode()"

Tags: oracle, xpath, mybatis

i have following situation.
this is my mybatis sql statement:

```
<select id="select" parameterType="String" resultMap="urlList">
    select 
                x.t002_id
    from
                 t002_metadata x  
    where
        existsNode(x.t002_xml, ?) = 1;
</select>
```

so when i'm calling the select method from the wrapper class and set the string parameter with a xpath expression, the following error message shows up:

```
Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1
```

Is it not possible for mybatis to make a prepared statement with existNode method from oracle??

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.  You shouldn't code the ? into your MyBatis xml.  MyBatis has special language for dynamic sql, I suggest reading the [MyBatis 3 User Guide](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/downloads/detail?name=MyBatis-3-User-Guide.pdf).

Change your sql map,

```
<select id="select" parameterType="String" resultMap="urlList">
    select 
                x.t002_id
    from
                 t002_metadata x  
    where
        existsNode(x.t002_xml, #{id}) = 1;
</select>
```

It might not be #{id}, it depends on how you call select from Mybatis.  For example, you might be using the @Param tag.